# Pass parameters to mainwindow ui from dialog ui qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have two UI:

mainwindow:[image]

dialog:
[image]

I want to send dialogs text's to mainwindow list.

I have tried:
in mainwindow cpp:

```
void MainWindow::on_ok_cancel_accepted()
{
    if (add)
    {
        std::unique_ptr<rsu> baz(new rsu);
        baz->id = uid->ID->text().toStdString();
        baz->name = uid->Name->text().toStdString();
        baz->coorx = uid->CoorX->text().toFloat();
        baz->coory = uid->CoorY->text().toFloat();
        baz->ip = uid->IP->text().toStdString();
        baz->port = uid->Port->text().toInt();
        r.push_back(*baz);
        rsuitem = new QListWidgetItem(QString::fromUtf8(baz->name.c_str()),ui->listRSU);
        rsuitem->setFlags(rsuitem->flags() | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);
        rsuitem->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
        clear_all();
        uid->rsuWidget->hide();
    }
    else
    {
        //QListWidgetItem *it = ui->listRSU->takeItem(itSelected);
        for (unsigned long i=0 ; i< r.size(); i++)
        {
            if (r[i].name == ui->Name->text().toStdString())
            {
                r[i].id = uid->ID->text().toStdString();
                r[i].name = uid->Name->text().toStdString();
                r[i].coorx = uid->CoorX->text().toFloat();
                r[i].coory = uid->CoorY->text().toFloat();
                r[i].ip = uid->IP->text().toStdString();
                r[i].port = uid->Port->text().toInt();
            }
        }
        rsuitem = new QListWidgetItem(uid->Name->text(),ui->listRSU);
        rsuitem->setFlags(rsuitem->flags() | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);
        rsuitem->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
        uid->rsuWidget->hide();
    }
    enable_all();
}
```

uid-> dialog

ui-> mainwindow

my second try:
in mainwindow cpp:

```
void MainWindow::acceptedbutton()
{
    if (add)
    {
        std::unique_ptr<rsu> baz(new rsu);
        baz->id = uid->ID->text().toStdString();
        baz->name = uid->Name->text().toStdString();
        baz->coorx = uid->CoorX->text().toFloat();
        baz->coory = uid->CoorY->text().toFloat();
        baz->ip = uid->IP->text().toStdString();
        baz->port = uid->Port->text().toInt();
        r.push_back(*baz);
        rsuitem = new QListWidgetItem(QString::fromUtf8(baz->name.c_str()),ui->listRSU);
        rsuitem->setFlags(rsuitem->flags() | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);
        rsuitem->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
        clear_all();
        uid->rsuWidget->hide();
    }
    else
    {
        //QListWidgetItem *it = ui->listRSU->takeItem(itSelected);
        for (unsigned long i=0 ; i< r.size(); i++)
        {
            if (r[i].name == ui->Name->text().toStdString())
            {
                r[i].id = uid->ID->text().toStdString();
                r[i].name = uid->Name->text().toStdString();
                r[i].coorx = uid->CoorX->text().toFloat();
                r[i].coory = uid->CoorY->text().toFloat();
                r[i].ip = uid->IP->text().toStdString();
                r[i].port = uid->Port->text().toInt();
            }
        }
        rsuitem = new QListWidgetItem(uid->Name->text(),ui->listRSU);
        rsuitem->setFlags(rsuitem->flags() | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);
        rsuitem->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
        uid->rsuWidget->hide();
    }
    enable_all();
}
```

my signal:

```
connect(dia, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SLOT((acceptedbutton())));
```

dia my dialog.

signal defined in mainwindow.h

I think I can't connect the signal correctly. I actually don't know how to connect them

Comment: `SLOT((acceptedbutton())));` - this is not a correct SLOT definition - there are to many parenthesis around the slot. Check the return value of the connect() call or use the new signal slot syntax properly described in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/signalsandslots.html#a-small-example) to catch such errors on compile time.

Comment: Yes you rigtht thank you but doesn't work again